# background image not showing on GitHub page

Tags: html, background-image

I want to learn some frontend and I am building simple website. It is published on GitHub pages, but the background image is not showing up. It works great on localhost but not on GitHub pages. This is the code I use inside the head tag of the index page:

```
<style>
        body {
            background-image: url("watch.jpg");
        }
</style>
```

watch.jpg and index.html are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

first check u can access image link directly in browser
`https://<username>.github.io/img.jpg`
if u cant access double check your image name and also check u don't miss a body html tag